# golang map comparison: partial match

Tags: dictionary, go, comparison

I am looking to compare received HTTP request headers with a map of expected headers being stored as part of a struct:

```
type Request struct {
    URI    string
    Method string
    Headers map[string]interface{}
}
```

I need to make sure that the Headers defined in the struct exist in the incoming request. I don't care if there are extra headers I wasn't expecting, but all headers stored in the struct must be present.

Is there a golang convention for determining whether all items in a map exist in another map? Some example data:

```
{
  "expected_headers": {
    "Content-Type": ["application/json"],
    "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate"]
  },
  "received_headers": {
    "Content-Type": ["application/json"],
    "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate"],
    "Accept": ["application/json"]
}
```

That is a positive example: i.e. the result of testing if the expected headers are present in the received headers should be True.

I know I could loop over the set of expected_headers and look for each of them in received_headers. However, I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing.

---

Based on the comments, I have added my solution. I freely admit that I'm brand new to Go (though I've been coding in many different languages for decades). My solution does not seem elegant to me. Better solutions welcome!

```
func contains(theSlice []string, theValue string) bool {
    for _, value := range theSlice {
        if value == theValue {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func slicesMatch(slice1 []string, slice2 []string) bool {
    for _, value := range slice1 {
        if !(contains(slice2, value)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func headersMatch(expected map[string][]string, actual http.Header) bool {
    for key, value := range expected {
        if !(slicesMatch(value, actual[key])) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is not "elegant" on a loop? Are loops bad practice in CS nowadays?

Comment: @Volker damn them kids withtheir fancy nonlooping ways, DAMN THEM.

Comment: Volker and @OneOfOne: I added my solution to my original question. While there may be a much better way to code it in Go, what I ended up with doesn't seem elegant to me. But then maybe I've spent too much time in "batteries included" languages...

Comment: @user3408000 joking aside, that is the idiomatic way to do it, anything else will be just synthetic sugar doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Well whaddya know... I'm on the right track! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a golang convention for determining whether all items in a map exist in another map?

No, there isn't. You will have to loop and check one at a time.